# How to get response from nodejs after posting data from reactjs to nodejs?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

This is my react code (works after entering url):

```
const SendToServer = (url) => {
  axios.post('http://localhost:4000/app/urls', url)
      .then(response => console.log(response))
  }
```

and this is the nodejs code:

```
router.post('/urls',(request, response)=>{
console.log(request.body.url);
console.log(request.body.depth);
var Crawler = require("simplecrawler");
var crawler = Crawler(request.body.url)
    .on("fetchcomplete", function (queueItem) {
        //console.log("Fetched a resource!",queueItem)
    });
    crawler.maxDepth = request.body.depth;
    crawler.maxConcurrency = 3;
    crawler.start();
```

How can I send the "queueItem" as a response to the reactjs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `response` object in your route middleware.

```
var crawler = Crawler(request.body.url)
    .on("fetchcomplete", function (queueItem) {
        response.status(200).send(queueItem);
    });
```

Comment: ```router.post('/urls', (request, response) => {
  req(webUrl, function (error, response, body) {
    console.error('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
    console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
    //console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage.
    //response.status(200).send(body);
    if (response.statusCode === 200) {
      response.send(body);
    }
  });``` with the request libary it doesnt work, how can i fix it?